# C# Populate 2 webpage text boxes with results from SQL database using a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web, dropdown

I am trying to populate 2 text boxes using a droplistlist
I have defined the dropdown list in the default.aspx as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Player" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="">Please Select</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>`

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Phocas_WorkBenchConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ID, [PlayerFirstName] + ' ' + [PlayerLastName] as 'Player' FROM [Players]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have created the C# code in the default.aspx.cs as follows:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-PMSK135\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Phocas_WorkBench;Integrated Security=True");
    {
        SqlCommand getFirstName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerFirstName from Players where ID = @PlayerID", sql);
        SqlCommand getLastName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerLastName from Players where ID = @PlayerID", sql);
        getFirstName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        getLastName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

        TextBox3.Text = getFirstName.CommandText;


        sql.Open(); //Opens Connection to the SQL Database using the definded Connection String. In this case the defined connection string is stored in "sql"
        string getResults = (string)getFirstName.ExecuteScalar();
        TextBox3.Text = getResults;
        getResults = (string)getLastName.ExecuteScalar();
        TextBox4.Text = getResults;
        sql.Close();

    }
}
```

I am hoping to populate the results from the 2 SqlCommands into textbox3 and textbox4 with @PlayerID being equal to the results stored in the dropdownlist with the DataValueField="ID" as ID is the Unique identifier

Thank you

**EDIT**
There was an error with my SQL query where the "WHERE " Statement was based on a name not a ID. This was a mistake and it was always meant to be ID.

I can confirm the code still does not work with the corrected SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that you have a wrong SQL statement in your default.aspx.cs. You should select the player's first and last name based on the ID. You can do this in 1 statement:

```
SqlCommand getPlayerName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerFirstName, PlayerLastName  from Players where ID = @PlayerID", sql);
```

As you are concatenating first and last name in the dropdown to display the full name you cannot use this concatenated value in the WHERE clause

Comment: Sorry, that was an error with my SQL query where the "WHERE " Statement was based on a name not a ID. This was a mistake and it was always meant to be ID.

I can confirm the code still does not work with the corrected SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql query should be this

```
SqlCommand getFirstName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerFirstName from Players where Id= @PlayerID", sql);
    SqlCommand getLastName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerLastName from Players where Id= @PlayerID", sql);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an error with my SQL query where the "WHERE " Statement was based on a name not a ID. This was a mistake and it was always meant to be ID.

I can confirm the code still does not work with the corrected SQL Query